# Get the URLs of opened tabs in Chrome .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Hello Can help with this code

i try to get all chrome tab's Url and insert them in listbox

, the project already run without any Error.

Code Form 1 :

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports NDde.Client

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function FindWindow(
ByVal lpClassName As String,
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr,
              ByVal childAfter As IntPtr,
              ByVal lclassName As String,
              ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim h As IntPtr
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome")
        h = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", p.MainWindowTitle)
        Exit For
    Next
    Dim urlH As IntPtr
    urlH = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Chrome_OmniboxView", Nothing)
    Dim urlHH As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100)
    Dim NumText As Integer = SendMessage(urlH, &HD, 50, urlHH)
    Dim url As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(urlHH)
    ListBox1.Items.Add(url)
End Sub
End Class
```

The Error : [Error Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnGhG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find something more easy(using Autohotkey.exe in your project resource)

- you can use ahk, to get your currently active Tab url, in addition copy url function
- make timer to paste copied from cliboard.

i think that all you can make. it hard to get compatible System.Windows.Automation

Comment: but problem is i cant find a good ahk that help me to get and copied the currently google chrome url.